# How to avoid instanceof from this kind of case?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, polymorphism

My current code in Player.java is like this:

```
    public boolean canPutCard(Card card) {
        if (!handCards.contains(card)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (card instanceof ActivableCard) {
            boolean hasEmpty = false;
            int i = card instanceof CharacterCard ? 0 : 1;
            for (int j = 0; j < fieldCards[i].length; ++j) {
                if (fieldCards[i][j] == null) {
                    hasEmpty = true;
                }
            }
            if (!hasEmpty) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return (card instanceof LandCard && !hasPutLandCard) || (card instanceof PoweredCard
                && ((PoweredCard) card).getPowerNeeded() <= currentElementValue[card.getElementType().ordinal()]);
    }
```

I want to avoid using of multiple instanceofs here because of what they call it "code smells" and use polymorphism instead. So what I can do is to rewrite it to be like this:

```
    public boolean canPutCard(LandCard card) {
        return !hasPutLandCard;
    }

    public boolean canPutCard(PoweredCard card) {
        return card.getPowerNeeded() <= currentElementValue[card.getElementType().ordinal()];
    }

    private boolean canPutCard(int i, PutableCard card) {
        boolean hasEmpty = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < fieldCards[i].length; ++j) {
            if (fieldCards[i][j] == null) {
                hasEmpty = true;
            }
        }
        return hasEmpty;
    }

    public boolean canPutCard(PutableCard card) {
        return canPutCard(1, card);
    }

    public boolean canPutCard(CharacterCard card) {
        return canPutCard(0, card);
    }

    public boolean canPutCard(Card card) {
        return handCards.contains(card);
    }
```

classes:

```
abstract class SkillCard extends Card implements PoweredCard
class CharacterCard extends Card implements PoweredCard, PutableCard
class LandCard extends Card
```

But, surely it won't work because it doesn't check every cases..

Is it possible to avoid instanceof and use polymorphism instead in this case?

Comment: You can make canPutCard method a generic method, but your fieldsCards has at least 2 dimensions, and dimensions are dependent different type of cards, I saw one for CharacterCard and the other for PutableCard, so you have to use instanceof to determine which dimension you look for, on the other hand you have hasPutLandCard boolean attribute for type of LandCard, this means also instanceof.

Comment: I don't get how generic method can solve this issue...

Comment: *"I want to avoid using of multiple instanceofs here because of what they call it "code smells""* ... so do all who live to see such code, but that is not for them to decide.  All you have to decide is what to do with the code that has been given you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instanceof operator can usually be replaced with proper reliance on java virtual dispatch. Move decision logic to Card class, like this

```
public abstract boolean canPutCard(Player player);
```

And then implement appropriate logic in Card subclasses like:

```
class LandCard extends Card {
    @Override public boolean canPutCard(Player player) {
         return !player.hasPutLandCard() && player.handContains(this);
    }
}

class CharacterCard extends Card implements PoweredCard, PutableCard {
    @Override public boolean canPutCard(Player player) {
         return !player.hasEmptyCharacterCardField() && player.handContains(this);
    }
}
```

... and so on. Player class will need to have required query methods.

Comment: *"Instanceof operator can usually be replaced with proper reliance on java virtual dispatch. "* ... Indeed.  However, this assumes that you are in control of the hierarchy and that you are able to modify the code base.  If not, then ... well ... instanceof gets you by.

Comment: this can work out, but if `Card` receiving `Player` as parameter while `Player` itself has `Card`s, isn't it tight coupling and isn't it bad design?

Comment: @nafkhanzam you could make an interface that cards receive as parameter instead of concrete class, if tight coupling to Player is a concern, You already have less coupling here than before since Player doesn't depend on card hierarchy details